# Rails 3: How to test router scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, routes

I'm using Rails 3.0 and I have the following in my routes.rb files:

```
scope "/:location" do
  resources :agents
end
```

So I can do this:

```
agents = Agent.where("location = ?", params[:location])
```

(There might be a better way to do this..?  Mostly I want URLs like: `myurl.com/london/agents`)

Anyway, my problem is with the tests (which I'm still learning), how can I make this work with the scope:

```
class AgentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get index" do
    get 'index'
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

It just gets a route no found error.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have scoped your resources, you don't actually have direct access to the agents_controller via any actions. So calling get 'index' is really just trying to access /agents. If you tried this in your browser, it would fail as well.

To get a success you'll have to supply a location param like so:

```
get 'index', { :location => 'hawaii' }
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: If you want additional access to the agents_controller (meaning location is optional) simply add a top-level resource for it in your routes file:

```
resources :agents
```

Comment: That's great, thanks!  (I actually thought I'd tried that and it failed, but I must have done something wrong as it all passes now - so cheers)